# Sequence of random variables that follow WLLN but not SLLN

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

I have to contruct a sequence of random variables that follow Weak Law of Large Numbers, but don't follow Strong Law of Large Numbers. Can canyone give me any hint please? Basically i need to choose such a sequence of integrable r.v-s that:

1) $$(S_n-\mathbb{E}S_n)/n \rightarrow 0 \qquad \mbox{in probability}$$

and

2) $$\mathbb{P}(\{\omega:(S_n-\mathbb{E}S_n)/n \rightarrow 0 \})<1$$

$S_n:=X_1+\ldots+X_n$

The only thing I know is that if $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ were identically distributed and independent, then its impossible.

Comment: Pretty sure there's a typo or a misunderstanding here - LLN says that $(S_n-\mathbb ES_n)/n\to0$ in some sense or other, where $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$.

Comment: Are you sure you're including all the requirements? Simply taking $X_n=X_1$ seems like a solution to the problem as you stated it...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : it would then follow the strong law too. But I agree, the question is badly asked

Comment: @Tryss I don't see why. Yes, I realized before you spoke up that my second comment was totally wrong. But the reason is that then $(X_n)$ does not satisfy the weak LLN...

Comment: My second comment was totally stupid, sorry. That said, I  still find it hard to believe that independence is not part of the requirements; without independence it's just too easy. Not quite as easy as in my second comment - before writing it out you might verify that no,  there really are no conditions other than what you said...

Comment: Whoever made that close vote: How the heck is this question "not about math, as defined in the help center"???

Comment: I corrected $S_n$ - thanks, it was typo

Comment: I would be grateful for examples if we don't assume anything and when we assume independence or common distribution. And sorry guys for my bad English...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/13433/

Comment: I doubt the accepted solution is what your TA has in mind.

Comment: What do you mean by TA?

Comment: Professor (TA actually means Teaching Assistant). (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did, it was not an assignment from my TA.

Comment: OK. Then why do you "have to contruct a sequence of random variables that" etc.?

Comment: Maybe it sounds like this because English is not my first language. Basically im refreshing probability "stuff" on my own. I was just wondering if such an example exists (when weak law holds, and strong does not). Now I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counterexample to the question exactly as stated is very simple. Let $A_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb C$ be any sequence of functions that tends to $0$ in measure but not pointwise. Ok, also say $\int_0^1 A_n=0$. Let $S_n=nA_n$, then let $X_1=S_1$ and $X_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$ for $n>1$.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? I just don't understand how this sequence "works" for weak law but not for strong law...

Comment: Do you believe that there exist functions $A_n$ that tend to $0$ in measure but not pointwise? If so: trace through the equations I gave and you see $A_n=(1/n)(X_1+\dots+X_n)$. So $(1/n)(X_1+\dots+X_n)\to0$ in measure but not almost surely.

Comment: Such functions can be $A_n(x)=x^{n}$ on $[0,1]$?

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you're missing here, but if you really think those functions do not tend to $0$ almost everywhere it follows that you're missing something much more basic than the details of the example I gave. My advice is find a book on measure theory and read up on almost everywhere convergence and convergence in measure...